# Facebook, Tabs posting in new window for links and FORM

Tags: javascript, php, jquery, facebook, iframe

I have built a Facebook tab application (PHP/JS), which consists of a form which posts to a database.
However whenever POSTing this will force open a new window and display the rest of the app there. Links also behave in this manor and are forced to leave the tabbed iframe in a new window.

How do I keep this inside the app?
So form POST to the DB, but not leave the iframe

```
<form id="form1" method="post" action="submit.php" >
......
</form>
```

Then the submit.php once posted entries to DB will do something like

```
header('Location: /thanks.php');
```

Answer (score 2, accepted):

I think you are looking for this ?

```
<form id="form1" method="post" action="submit.php" target="_self" >
......
</form>
```

The target="_self" keeps the submit within the iframe.